# Press Kit proof-read in exchange for an app license?

Tags: beta-readers, freelance

I would like to find someone who would proof-read a Press Kit of an Mac OS X app in exchange for a license. Do you know any website / service where I could find some English native speaker, ideally technical writer, who would be interested in an offer like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you offer a free license, I would ask people you know directly. Easier and more promising than online.

Sites taking licenses as payment do not exist as far as I know. But there are free services out there. Maybe you want to check them:

[PaperRater](http://www.paperrater.com)
[Kibin](http://www.appappeal.com/app/kibin/)

I haven't tested any of them. Also take a look at the [Startups StackExchange](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/4188/good-proofreading-site) site.

Answer (score 1):

Places where you can find technical writers:

- Society for Technical Communication - http://stc.org
- Your local STC chapter.
- Technical Writer Mailing List (TechWhirl) - http://techwhirl.com/
- Write the Docs - http://www.writethedocs.org/
- Technical Writing World: - http://technicalwritingworld.com/
- Any number of groups on LinkedIn, Google+, etc.
- A local college or university that has a program or even a single course offering in technical writing. Students are always looking for ways to build a portfolio of writing samples.